# Display a loop of div's with a href click me button to display the text in that div

Tags: php

I have a bit of an issue. I am trying to do a while loop in a database which will load information about each person. In the field I want it to load a contact form but hide it on initial load. I have this working My problem is when I go to click the button it displays all the Div's when I only want it to display that div the button was clicked on. Below is just a simple example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

$x = 1; 

while($x <= 5) {
  echo '<div class ="Test_name">Hello World</div> <br>
  <a  href = "#" class = "Click_ME" > Click to show</a>';
  $x++;
} 
?>

<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".Test_name" ).hide();
  $('.Click_ME').html('TEST');
  $( ".Click_ME" ).click(function() {

    $( ".Test_name" ).show();

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery selector should be point to the respective div on click of button.

Inside click event using `$(".Click_ME").index(this)` we can able to find index of clicked button's index and using it div can show using `$( ".Test_name" ).eq($(".Click_ME").index(this)).show();`.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".Test_name" ).hide();
  $( ".Click_ME" ).on('click',function() {
    //$(".Click_ME").index(this) will find the index of clicked button and based on that index div can show/hide.
    $( ".Test_name" ).eq($(".Click_ME").index(this)).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="Test_name">Hello World</div> <br>
<a  href = "#" class = "Click_ME" > Click to show</a>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class ="Test_name">Hello World</div> <br>
<a  href = "#" class = "Click_ME" > Click to show</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$( ".Test_name" ).show();` with `$(this).prevAll('.Test_name').first();`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

folow this simple steps.

- In the div include the style `display:none`

  ```
  <div style='display:none'>
      // you all php data here
  </div>
  ```
- on click remove the style

  ```
  $( ".Click_ME" ).click(function() {

      $(".Test_name").css('display','block');

  });
  ```